# How to pass colors to echo in bash find -exec command?

Tags: bash, colors, find, echo

I would like to pass colors to an echo command executed after find results:

For example this works:

```
RED='\033[0;31m'
echo -e "${RED}Red"
```

But this one does not work:

```
RED='\033[0;31m'
find . -print -name test -exec bash -c 'echo -e "${RED}{}"' \;
```

Is this not possible in this way, or is another option like using -printf better? My goal would be to see find output (with -print) and highlight in another color executed find results! Thanks for help or input!

Comment: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to export `RED` variable since `-exec bash -c` spawns a new subshell and `RED` isn't available to child shell unless it is exported:

```
export RED='\033[0;31m'
```

Also `find` command should be:

```
find . -name test -exec bash -c 'echo -e "${RED}{}"' \;
```

You have an extra `-print` that will print all entries not just named `test`.

Prefer this form of passing filename to `bash -c` in argument list:

```
find . -name 'test' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "$RED$1"' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I am new to bash as you see... I do want to see the verbose output from find, therefor I set the -print option.